# Regarding query for db2

Tags: mysql, database

I have the query, I have the below relationships among the following tables

```
select * from PRODGP_STRUCTURE
select * from PRODGP_STR_LINK
select * from PRODUCT_GROUP
select * from PROD_PGRP_LINK
select * from PRODUCT
```

the relationship is ...

```
select pstr.PSTR_NAME, PG.PRGP_NAME, PRD.PROD_NAME
from prodgp_structure pstr
JOIN PRODGP_STR_LINK pgstrlnk
  ON pgstrlnk.PSTR_ID = pstr.PSTR_ID  
JOIN PRODUCT_GROUP pg 
  ON pgstrlnk.PRGP_CHILD_ID = PG.PRGP_ID
JOIN PROD_PGRP_LINK prdprdgp
  ON prdprdgp.PRGP_ID = pg.PRGP_ID
JOIN product prd
  ON prdprdgp.PROD_ID = prd.PROD_ID;
```

I have come up to the following query,

```
select * from PRODGP_STRUCTURE where pstr_id in 
(select pstr_id from PRODGP_STR_LINK where PRGP_CHILD_ID  in
(select  prgp_id from PRODUCT_GROUP where PRGP_ID in ( select  PRGP_ID from PROD_PGRP_LINK where PROD_ID in ( select PROD_ID from product where PROD_ID=2))))
```

Please let e know is there any other way to write this query..!!

Answer (score 0):

Inner join your tables together and then you will only need to filter by the PROD_ID

```
SELECT pstr.PSTR_NAME, PG.PRGP_NAME, PRD.PROD_NAME
FROM prodgp_structure pstr
INNER JOIN PRODGP_STR_LINK pgstrlnk
  ON pgstrlnk.PSTR_ID = pstr.PSTR_ID  
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_GROUP pg 
  ON pgstrlnk.PRGP_CHILD_ID = PG.PRGP_ID
INNER JOIN PROD_PGRP_LINK prdprdgp
  ON prdprdgp.PRGP_ID = pg.PRGP_ID
INNER JOIN product prd
  ON prdprdgp.PROD_ID = prd.PROD_ID
WHERE prd.PROD_ID = 2;
```